# Checkpoints are occurring too frequently during pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, restore, configuration, checkpoint

Under PostgreSQL 9.2.2 (Windows 32 bits), I have a `pg_restore` command that systematically results in log warnings about the checkpoint frequency, for example:

```
LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (17 seconds apart)
HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "checkpoint_segments".
```

The database is about 3.3 Gb in size with 112 tables/160 views and restores in about 14 minutes.

Is it normal for that to occur during a `pg_restore`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not uncommon during a whole-DB restore because that's an exceptionally huge operation. If you see this during normal operation, consider raising your setting for `checkpoint_segments` permanently, just like the error message hints.

You might go to the trouble of setting `checkpoint_segments` higher just before the restore and then lower it again. This is even what [the manual suggests (including an explanation)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/populate.html#POPULATE-CHECKPOINT-SEGMENTS):

> Temporarily increasing the [`checkpoint_segments`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-CHECKPOINT-SEGMENTS) configuration variable
>   can also make large data loads faster. This is because loading a large
>   amount of data into PostgreSQL will cause checkpoints to occur more
>   often than the normal checkpoint frequency (specified by the
>   `checkpoint_timeout` configuration variable). Whenever a checkpoint
>   occurs, all dirty pages must be flushed to disk. By increasing
>   `checkpoint_segments` temporarily during bulk data loads, the number of
>   checkpoints that are required can be reduced.

Related answer with more details:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for write performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10208/configuring-postgresql-for-write-performance)

#### Postgres 9.5

The upcoming new release has a smarter approach. Quoting the [beta release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/release-9-5.html#AEN126034):

> Replace configuration parameter `checkpoint_segments` with `min_wal_size`
>   and `max_wal_size` (Heikki Linnakangas)
>
> This allows the allocation of a large number of WAL files without
>   keeping them if they are not needed. Thus the default for `max_wal_size`
>   has been increased to `1GB`.

Aside: the number of views is barely relevant, those do not contain any data, just the "recipe", i.e.: the query and some attributes of the view. For the question at hand, basically only the total size of the backup file matters.

Comment: After setting checkpoint_segments to 30, no more of these messages appear in the log. Thanks.